# How to change the default MainMenu.xib file in a Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I was programming some stuff in a Xcode project, then I decided to move all that code and xib file to a new project. So, I've created a new project, then copied the files to their new place.

The thing is: the new project already had an MainMenu.xib file. I deleted the default (the one that comes within the new project) and added my MainMenu.xib from the other project.

It compiles and run. But when I click some buttons nothing happens. I checked the actions and outlets links, and it seems to be fine.

What else should I look for to get that main window working properly? Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the "Main Interface" setting in your target settings (Summary tab).

Comment: It is already set to "MainMenu". My main and only xib file is the MainMenu.xib. As I said, it runs and display everything on screen, but nothing happens when I click the buttons. =\

Comment: Is the File Owner's (NSApplication) delegate in the Main Menu.nib linked to your App delegate object?

Comment: I click in the MainMenu.xib, then right click on File's Owner. In the black popup menu I can see the "delegate--app delegate" link. Is that it what you mean?

Comment: Yes. And you also might want to check of the app delegate object in the nib has the right class.

Comment: Yes, it have the right class, the LGAppDelegate. I also found some interesting in the Console that may have something to do with this problem:

2012-06-25 15:34:13.020 GSOM[37807:403] Unknown class 'LGQueueController', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /Users/blablasomebigpath.../Contents/Resources/MainMenu.nib.
2012-06-25 15:34:13.075 GSOM[37807:403] Could not connect the action buttonProducerPushed: to target of class NSObject

Comment: Looks like one of the objects in the nib has the LQQueueController class which is apparently not included in your project or not enabled for your target.

Comment: Well, I removed the file from the project and added again, also made all the connections back. Now its working! Thanks a lot @Diederik